# Magento 2 Class

Tags: magento2, blocks, class

i'm trying to convert a module from Prestashop to Magento 2 but i have a problem with the class. I'm following several tutorial and my whole module is based on the administration part of the website.

so i'm trying to create a function that will make a simple "`SELECT * FROM 'mytable'`". I can already interact with my database with my controller but i can't with my block.

here is my actual block (the comment is my attempt of adapting a tutorial to my need)

```
namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class Contactslist extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    /*public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\Contact $contact,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_contact = $contact;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct(
            $context
            $data
        );
    }*/

    public function mycustom(){
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

and there is my controller who's supposed to be able to use the function who's suppose to make a `Select * From mytable`.

```
  namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Controller\Adminhtml\Nettoyage;


  class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
  {
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /*
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }


    public function execute()
    {

      // these line are just some test i made
        /*$contact = $this->_objectManager->create('Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\Contact');
        $data =[];
        $data['toreplace']="test1";
        $data['replaceby']="test2";
        $data['id']=2;
        $contact->setData($data);
        $contact->save();

        $data = $this->_objectManager->create('Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\Contact')->getCollection();
        foreach ($data as $d )  {
            echo $d->getToreplace();
            echo $d->getReplaceby();
        }*/


        return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
  }
```

did someone see something wrong or have an advice

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have the model (Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\Contact) and resource model for your table. You can use the same to retrieve the data.

```
 public function __construct(
         \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
         \Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ContactFactory $contactFactory,
         \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     ) {
          parent::__construct($context);
          $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
          $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
     }
```

And you can access the collection from your function `mycustom()` like below

```
public function mycustom(){
        $collection = $this->contactFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
```

Comment: i have an error<?php
namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class Contactslist extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
 
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ContactFactory $ContactFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->ContactFactory = $ContactFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
 
 public function mycustom(){
     echo "test";
 }
}

Comment: The above solution should work if you have created your module in a right direction

Comment: I hope you have the model class. If so, it should work. Please post the error you got(not the file).

Answer (score 0):

When you are extending block template your construct must match with the extended class

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Block\Adminhtml;

class Contactslist extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    private $ContactFactory;

    private $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, //Change this class
        \Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ContactFactory $ContactFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->ContactFactory = $ContactFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function mycustom(){
        echo "test";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you specify a little bit pls i didn't understand

Comment: The class you extend the parameters should be same. In your case you are extending `\Magento\Backend\Block\Template` so in your construct you need to pass the extended class context which is `\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context`

Answer (score 0):

Add Parent Construct Here

```
namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

 protected $ContactFactory;

    protected $resultPageFactory;

class Contactslist extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ContactFactory $ContactFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
     array $data = []
) {
    $this->ContactFactory = $ContactFactory;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function mycustom(){
    echo "test";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mix of your answer and it worked thanks you all (sorry for my bad using of the forum withe the answer and comment i'm new)

here what i get

```
<?php
namespace ManoMano\AdminPage\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class Contactslist extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

 public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
     \ManoMano\AdminPage\Model\ContactFactory $contactFactory,
     \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
     array $data = []
 ) {
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
      $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
      $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
 }

public function mycustom(){
    $data = array();
    $model = $this->contactFactory->create();
    $data['toreplace']="test1";
    $data['replaceby']="test2";
    $data['id']=2;
    $model->setData($data);
    try {
        $model->save();
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

     $newData = $model->getCollection();
        foreach ($newData as $d )  {
            echo $d->getToreplace();
            echo $d->getReplaceby();
        }
}
```

}